# How to find out if a specific task is running in Domino Server from Java?

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-domino

from a JavaServerAddin I trigger an agent that invokes another program on a domino server. The program takes a little time to run. Normally, the addin schedule does not interfere with the program.
I would like to check from my JavaAddin if the program is still running and avoid invoking the agent when the result of the check returns true.

Anyone any idea, how to do this?

I've tried this (http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0593.html) and other samples, but it only returns tasks that are running on the server but not inside Domino

Comment: Have the Java app write to a file and check the file for the status of the previous running app.

Comment: please, add more details: your addin code invokes agent (how? agent.run? aget.runOnServer? console command?) and that agent (Java, LotusScript) invokes another program (how?)

Comment: how are you executing the external program? like here? http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html

Comment: The qotools program ( quickr 8.5.1) is triggered using NSFRemoteConsole(server, cmd, hBuf) from LotusScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you consider to issue a SHOW TASKS to the console. With -XML you get something that is easy to parse.

```
  Session s = ...;
  String result = s.sendConsoleCommand("yourserver","SHOW TASKS -XML");
```

Hope that helps

Comment: thx. this will do it for now.

I have changed the command to

String result = session.sendConsoleCommand("","!SHOW TASKS -XML");

to avoid the console output when the command is send to the server